# Is bitwise & equivalent to modulo operation

Tags: c

I came across the following snippet which in my opinion is to convert an integer into binary equivalence. 
Can anyone tell me why an &1 is used instead of %2 ? Many thanks.

```
for (i = 0; i <= nBits; ++i) {
    bits[i] = ((unsigned long) x & 1) ? 1 : 0;
    x = x / 2;
}
```

Comment: And what's up with that horrendous conditional expression? Shouldn't it be `(unsigned long) x & 1 != 0) ? (true ? 1 : 0) : (!true ? (x, 0), -0)`?

Comment: Yes, naturally :-) By the way, is the `<=` correct?

Comment: `x % n` is the same as `x & (n-1)` iff `n` is a power of 2.  I think people use the `&` form because they think it's a micro-optimization.

Comment: @Matt NcNabb: Not quite, rounding towards zero of signed integers causes trouble and is the reason for some such masking.

Comment: @doynax good point although doing bitwise operations on signed integers is inherently non-portable

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The representation of unsigned integers is specified by the Standard: An unsigned integer with *n* value bits represents numbers in the range [0, 2<sup>*n*</sup>), with the usual binary semantics. Therefore, the least significant bit is the remainder of the value of the integer after division by 2.

It is debatable whether it's useful to replace readable mathematics with low-level bit operations; this kind of style was popular in the 70s when compilers weren't very smart. Nowadays I think you can assume that a compiler will know that dividing by two can be realized as bit shift etc., so you can just Write What You Mean.

Comment: When working with single bits or bitwise operations, I feel that using & instead of % is much more natural. After all, they are only equivalent in _this special case_.

Comment: I think the question here is not whether the compiler knows x/2 = x>>1, but rather if it knows to replace the % operation with & a operation. The answer to that is no, it does not!

Comment: @Pandrei: The compiler isn't generally allowed to modify your source code! But it will probably generate the same machine code for both versions of the source code.

Comment: @KerrekSB I was referring to the generated code. So your answer does not really address the question in my opinion.

Comment: @Jan: Well, perhaps. If you really want to do bit-wise operations, of course you should use bit-wise operations. Whether this situation calls for it is debatable; in some sense it's computing the "digits of an integer in a place-value representation", which is generally done with divide and remainder, and doesn't call for being "specialized" for base two. But it depends.

Comment: @Pandrei: Please feel free to post your own answer!

Answer (score 1):

what the code snippet does, is not to convert a unsigned int into a binary number (it's internal representation is already binary). It created a bit array with the values of the unsigned int's bits. Spreads it out over an array if you will.

```
e.g. x=3  =>  bits[2]=0 bits[1]=1 bits[0]=1
```

To do this

1. it selects the last bit of the number and places it the `bits` array
   (the &1 operation).
2. then shifts the number to the right by one position ( /2 is
   equivalent to >>1).
3. Repeats the above operations for all the bits

You could have used %2 instead of &1, the generated code should be the same. But I guess it's just a matter of programming style and preference. For most programmers, the &1 is a lot clearer than %2.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `%2` and `&1` are the same. Which one to take is probably simply a matter of taste. While `%2` is probably more easier to read for people with a strong mathematics background, `&1` is easier to understand for people with a strong technical background.

Comment: To be consistent, I think `x % 2` should be used with `x /= 2`; and `x & 1` should be used with `x >>= 1` .  I have a strong mathematics background and prefer `%` so you may be right there :)

Comment: Thank you guys for all your input!

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent in the very special case. It's an old Fortran influenced style.